# Visual Studio 2015 does not remember undocked windows position between debug and coding views

Tags: visual-studio-2015

An issue started happening with VS2015. All was working fine for a while and then it suddenly stopped remembering the position of my undocked tools windows when the "view" switches between debug and coding.

All my undocked windows get repositioned in the middle of the main visual studio monitor.

Even rearranging the toolboxes, doing Window > Save window Layout, and then trying to apply that layout screws up.

Maybe relevant info : 
 - multiproject C# solution.
 - multiple monitors (3)
 - windows 7 pro

Anybody has a fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out it was an issue with my triple monitor setup. (I use a Matrox TripleHead2Go display port.)

The issue was that the Matrox PowerDesk / Desktop Management settings where screwing around with Visual Studio's window layout settings.

All I had to do was uncheck the "Center Dialog Boxes and message boxes" settings :

[image]